# How to iterate over an state array in React and conditionally delay the next iteration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

**Project:** I'm building a Chatbot and I want to render the messages of the Chatbot sequentially with a delay between each other.

**Problem**: The messages are saved in a state array. So far I was using `map` in the JSX of my *ChatScreen* Component to return a *ChatBotMessage* component containing the actual message. Since `map` doesn't support async behavior (except for resolving all promises with `Pomise.all()` which is not helpful in my case), I have tried to use a `for..of` loop. The problem here is that I can't return the *ChatBotMessage* component within the loop, because as soon as I return something the loop stops.

**Wanted Behavior**: I need to find a way too iterate through the state array and display the latest messages with a delay from within JSX. The state object looks like this:

```
messages = [
{type: text,
 text: 'Chatbot message'
},
{type: 'typing',
value: true
},
{type: text,
 text: 'Chatbot message'
},
{type: 'typing',
value: true
}
....
]
```

Every time the iteration hits an element of type = 'typing' that is set to true, it should delay the next message. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**: Added the *ChatScreen* Component:

```
export const ChatScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const messageState: MessagesState = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.messagesState)
    const userState: User = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.userState)


    const scrollToRef: any = useRef();
    const scrollToBottom = () => {
        if (scrollToRef.current) {
            scrollToRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!messageState.loadedHistory && !messageState.updatingHistory) {
            dispatch(requestMessagesHistory(userState.id))
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const onFocus = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            if (!messageState.loaded && !messageState.updating && messageState.loadedHistory && !messageState.updatingHistory) {
                dispatch(requestMessagesInitial(userState.id));
            }
        });
        return onFocus;
    }, [navigation]);


        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView
                    ref={scrollToRef}
                    onContentSizeChange={() => {
                        if (scrollToRef.current) {
                            scrollToRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })
                        }
                    }
                    style={styles.containerInner}>
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
                        <View style={styles.chatArea}>
                          {*Here I need to iterate over the message array and return the Chat Messages*}
                            {messageState.messages.map((item, index, arr) => {
                                if (item.type === 'text' && item.text !== 'init') {
                                    if (!item.human) {
                                        return <ChatMessageBot index={index} text={item.text} />
                                    } else if (item.human) {
                                        return <ChatMessageHuman index={index} message={item.text} />
                                    } else {
                                        return <ChatMessageBot index={index} text={item.text} />;
                                    }
                                } 
                            })}
                        </View>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm probably not interpreting your question the way you meant it, but i think if you pre-process the array to add a `delay: {number}` field to the message objects, and then you make the component that renders each message respect that delay internally, that might solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with the for loop. As you stated, `promise.all` isn't really useful as you need to chain the asynchronous waits sequentially.

You can use `async` `await` syntax to solve this relatively neatly.

Try something like this instead:

(Obviously this code isn't react code, but your issue is more fundamental than react)

```js
// Stub, replace with whatever is appropriate (e.g. React state update, or prop invocation)
const renderMessage = (message) => console.log('Message rendered: ', message);

const executeMessages = async (messages, delay) => {
    for(message of messages) {
        if (message.type === 'text') {
            renderMessage(message.value);
        } else if (message.type ==="typing" && message.value===true) {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, typingDelay)); // this creates a promise which will resolve after the typingDelay has elapsed
        }
    }
}

executeMessages([
  { type: "text", text: "Chatbot message" },
  { type: "typing", value: true },
  { type: "text", text: "Chatbot message" },
  { type: "typing", value: true },
], 3000); // 3000 is 3 seconds
```

Comment: I see how I can use the renderMessage function to console log the messages, but in my case I need to return a React Component, at the spot where I call executeMessages in my JSX and renderMessages will be called in the function body, but the only way I see this work is that renderMessages will push the message in a local state array which than will be mapped in the return statement, but that will probably trigger a lot of re-renders and seems quite hacky...?

Comment: Could you share a copy of your jsx so we can try and fit the solution in?

Comment: I have added a simplified version of my ChatScreen component

Answer (score 0):

I'm making this answer to give more context to my comment, which I'll repeat here:

I'm probably not interpreting your question the way you meant it, but i think if you pre-process the array to add a `delay: {number}` field to the message objects, and then you make the component that renders each message respect that delay internally, that might solve your problem.

Assuming I am interpreting your comment correctly, you preprocess your array to add a `delay` property to the right `messages`:

```
messages = [
{type: text,
 text: 'Chatbot message'
},
{type: 'typing',
value: true
},
{type: text,
 text: 'Chatbot message'
},
{type: 'typing',
value: true
},
{type: text,
 text: 'final message',
 delay: 2 // seconds
},
]
```

And then, I assume your JSX is something like

```
messages.map(message => <ChatBotMessage message={message} />)
```

So inside your ChatBotMessage, you create some state, maybe `delayed = true` and then a timeout function that will take your `delay` value, `this.props.message.delay || 0`, and inside the settimeout callback you set the state `delayed = false`.

Then in your render function, if delayed is true, return `null`.